# TypeScript Error: Type 'type' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 'type' & { children?: ReactNode; }'. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am doing a small home project to improve my skills in TS.
Getting data from server, everything is good, posts started to be displayed without errors, but then I decided to put the code with the map in a separate component and ts immediately gave me an error:

> Type '{ posts: IPost[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

`Main.tsx`

```js
export const Main: FC = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<IPost[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const fetchPost = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('/posts');
        setPosts(res.data);
      };
      fetchPost();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='main-container'>
        <NewPosts />
        <PostSort />
        <Posts posts={posts} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

`Posts.tsx`

```js
export const Posts: FC<IPost[]> = ({posts}) => {
  return (
    <div className='post-container'>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post key={post._id} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is the way you are defining your prop types under `Posts.tsx`. Any component props is by design an object, but you are defining it as an array.

You are saying that your props are of type `IPost[]` and then you are destructuring them to get a property called `posts`.

The easiest way to fix this, is to create a new type for the props of `Posts.tsx` and have a property `posts` of type `IPost[]`.

```
// create a new interface for prop types
interface PostsProps{
   posts: IPost[];
}


// pass it under the FC generic
export const Posts: FC<PostsProps> = ({posts}) => {
  return (
    <div className='post-container'>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post key={post._id} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```